# emacs ediff refresh buffers

Tags: emacs, emacs-ediff

I am using emacs ediff to compare two files that I frequently update. How can I refresh or update the buffer to reflect the new file without killing and reloading ediff? When I try to update each file using C-x C-v, the Ediff Control Panel says "You have killed a vital Ediff buffer--you must leave Ediff now!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Switch to the Emacs Ediff control panel and and press `!`.

That will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the file with `M-x revert-buffer`, and then hit `!` in the Ediff control panel to make Ediff recalculate the difference regions.

Answer (score 2):

Ediff have ediff-revert-buffers-then-recompute-diffs.

From the ediff manual
[ediff-revert-buffers-then-recompute-diffs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ediff.html#index-ediff_002drevert_002dbuffers_002dthen_002drecompute_002ddiffs):

**ediff-revert-buffers-then-recompute-diffs:**
This command reverts the buffers you are comparing and recomputes their differences. It is useful when, after making changes, you decided to make a fresh start, or if at some point you changed the files being compared but want to discard any changes to comparison buffers that were done since then.